# Android emulator dosn't work in Project idx With flutter workspace

Tags: android, flutter, idx

I created a Flutter project on project idx, everything works fine and runs on the web, but the problem is that the Android emulator doesn't work and there are no obvious problems.

```
 2024-03-30T04:33:43Z [android] : Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
 2024-03-30T04:33:43Z [android] : Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
 2024-03-30T04:33:47Z [android] : ✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
 2024-03-30T04:33:55Z [android] : Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
 2024-03-30T04:33:55Z [android] : App state changed to : RUNNING
```

Has anyone faced the same problem?

[project idx screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Ael.png)

I created a Flutter project on project idx, everything works fine and runs on the web, but the problem is that the Android emulator doesn't work and there are no obvious problems.

Comment: could you paste the error log